# C# Interop Excel quickly get cell indentation levels

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel-interop

I am trying to quickly load the text values from an excel spreadsheet into a 2d string array (Visual Studio, C#), and maintaining the indentation information is important. I managed to do it (albeit slow) with the following code:

```
    int indentLevel = msExcelRange.Cells[row, col]).IndentLevel;
    string rawText = msExcelRange.Cells[row, col]).Text;

    string spacesString = "";

    //Generate spaces-string proportional to indent level
    for(int i = 0; i < indentLevel; i++)
    {
        spacesString  = spacesString + " ";
    }

    //Append spaces to emulate indentation level
    return spacesString + rawText;
```

With this function, I just iterate over every single row and column. It was taking 15 minutes to load an entire Excel spreadsheet, so I'm searching for a faster way.

I came across this function which extracts the text more quickly (only a few seconds) :

```
object[,] rawText = msExcelRange.get_Value(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
```

But the indentation level is lost. Is there a similar function to quickly extract indentation?

Comment: Downvote? Constructive criticism would be appreciated.

Comment: Kudos for finding a better way to get _values, but unfortunately I don't think there's something similar for indentation level.

Comment: Also, I doubt it will make a significant difference but you could also just do `return new string(' ', indentLevel) + rawText;` instead of the loop and save a few string concatenations.

Comment: Is there any pattern to the indent level (e.g. all cells in a row or column have the same level) or is it more or less random?

Comment: Thanks for the input. The indentation is more or less random.

Comment: How many cells are you loading?  Do they all have values or do you just pick a huge range to be sure to get all of the data?  I'm trying to find ways to reduce the number of calls to `.IndentLevel` since that's the expensive part.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to account for every single cell in the excel file, regardless of it's size or row/col count.